# how do you write a 301 redirect regular expression for unknown values?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to 301 redirect with a regular expression in the .htaccess file. it needs to from example.com/about-me/blog/anything-could-be-here/ to example.com/anything could-be-here

I got this but I know it is wrong, I'm new to this and not sure what else to do.

```
RewriteRule ^about-me/blog/($) [R=301] /$1
```

any help figuring out how to do this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax and regex are incorrect.

You can use this `RedirectMatch` rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/about-me/blog/(.*)$ /$1
```

Using `mod_rewrite` it will be:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^about-me/blog/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for not down voting me and helping me out!